# Capturing gestures with OnTouchListeners

Tags: android, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to capture a gesture on android, I want to trigger an action when the user slideup over a view and another action when the user sliddown over the same view.
I'm using the SetOntouchListener to capture the gesture, here is the code:

```
        LinearLayout arrowIv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.arrowInfoPanel);
    arrowIv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

            Log.d("TAGTAG", "action: " + action);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And here is the output from my listener

```
    action: 0
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 2
    action: 1
```

The problem is: the onTouch event is called a lot of times and how can I process this and say "it was a slideUp action"? 
Another detail according to google "...ACTION_DOWN is the starting point for all touch events.", then even a slideUp start with a ACTION_DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

```
    arrowIv.imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
         public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
         public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
});

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                     if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }



    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you question that you want to detect if user slide up or down on your view? If i get your question, maybe this is a workaround for you.
as document:

> public static final int ACTION_DOWN A pressed gesture has started, the
>   motion contains the initial starting location.
>
> public static final int ACTION_UP A pressed gesture has finished, the
>   motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate
>   points since the last down or move event.

to know slide up or slide down i think you need to get the start position at ACTION_DOWN and end position at ACTION_UP. The difference of start position and end position will let you know slide up or down.

```
StartPostion.Y - EndPosition.Y > 0 => slide up
StartPostion.Y - EndPosition.Y < 0 => slide down
```